# ubuntu 13.10 secondary monitor - doesn't redraw properly

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nouveau

Hi I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo w350 and am having some issues with graphics driver.

standard nouveau drivers work great on the laptop display but when I attach an external display it goes bad on the external monitor, seems it's not re-drawing properly. (Photo attached).

I've tried other drivers but none of them detect the external monitor when connected.

Any ideas?

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] (rev a1)

screenshot of effected monitor -- [image: http://i.imgur.com/UZWMpQO.jpg]

UPDATE 1: I have noticed that if I leave the System Monitor open the display improves. Wierd.

UPDATE 2: If I leave a video going the lag/flicker issues stop.

Comment: I've been experiencing the very same issue and with the same behavior when a video is going, but only on my third monitor. Monitor #1 and #2 both redraw just fine.

Comment: I have the same problem! Can't seem to find any solutions either. Using the proprietary Nvidia drivers isn't something I want to do either, since it overheats my laptop :( Have you found a permanent solution to this yet?

Comment: Is this still reproducible?

Comment: I am having the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and a Dell Precision M4800. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: This sounds a lot like https://bugs.launchpad.net/nouveau/+bug/1228506 / https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70389

Answer (score 1):

I experienced exactly same behaviour on external monitor (connected through DVI or DisplayPort) when I booted Ubuntu 13.10 from USB stick.

I might have found workaround that solves redrawing problem.

**My system:** Lenovo T430 with 2 graphic cards (Integrated Intel and additional Nvidia).

**Workaround:** Go to the BIOS setup, in Graphics setup choose Discrete graphics. Redrawing problem occured only when there was Nvidia Optimus mode active.

Comment: Turning on "Discrete graphics" will overheat your machine.

Comment: I have the same laptop and problem, but selecting Discrete Graphics simply prevents Ubuntu from starting (all I get is a black screen in graphics mode with blinking cursor)